# Git - Authentication failed

Tags: git, cygwin, putty

I'm completely new at git, and having had prior knowledge with putty decided to set it up to use that.

At first it came up with an error I traced back (using google) to me not connecting via plink to the server to cache it.

I was able to connect via plink to the git repository I need to clone, but doing the "git clone x y" comes up with an authentication error?

I assume there's something big I'm missing here :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using ssh pubkey authentication, did you remember to set up your key properly? If you're using the PuTTY plink, you probably need to add your keypair to PageAnt; if you're using a cygwin one, you might need to put the key files in your `~/.ssh/` directory.

Comment: Well I set it up via putty too.. not sure what I could've done wrong really

Comment: Did you run Pageant and add your key to it?

Comment: Yup - but I restarted my pc and it worked fine, not too sure what the solution is so i'll just mark this as it because you tried :D